# Node.js request return Error: connect ECONNREFUSED when set options parameter

Tags: node.js, npm-request

request works fine if I send it with url with required attributes as first parameter but failed each time when trying to send with options object parameter that contains request attributes:

```
"use strict"
var https = require('https'),
    request = require('request');

var obj = {
    translate: function(textToTranslate) {
        var options = {
            url: "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate",
            qs: {
                key: process.env.TRANSLATION_APP_TOKEN,
                lang: "en-ru",
                text: textToTranslate
            }
        }, translationRequest = https.request(options, function(response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(chunk).text[0]);
            });
        });
        console.log(options);

        translationRequest.on('error', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        translationRequest.end();
    }
};

obj.translate("hello");
```

I'm using qs option to pass parameters but tried formData and body but it doesn't work as well.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using the `request` module (that you've already got loaded) instead of `https`. And according to [the docs](https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/#JSON), you need to pass these parameters via a GET request as query params (so POST form data won't work):

```
"use strict"
var https = require('https'),
    request = require('request');

var obj = {
    translate: function(textToTranslate) {
        var options = {
            url: "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate",
            qs: {
                key: "<redacted>",
                lang: "en-ru",
                text: textToTranslate
            }
        }
        request.get(options, function(e, r, body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
    }
};

obj.translate("hello");
```

Tested it against the API with a valid key, and got this response:

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["привет"]}
```

For what it's worth, the reason it doesn't work like you've done it with `options` with the `https` module, is because that is the syntax designed for `request` not `https`. For `https` to work, you need to follow that schema:

```
options = {
    hostname: "translate.yandex.net",
    path: "/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + process.env.TRANSLATION_APP_TOKEN + "&lang=en-ru&text=" + textToTranslate
}
```

(Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)